# Transitioning Between Index Paths in a DetailViewController? Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing, segue

So using the code below, I've segued my `CollectionViewCell` indexPath into the new `DetailViewController`. now each `DetailViewController displays what is contained in the array of the indexPath selected.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let animal: Animal!
    let anims: [Animal] = dataSource.anims

    animal = anims.filter{ $0.isDefault }[indexPath.row]

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailVC", sender: animal)
    }
}
```

So that means the new `DetailVC`will be able to pull the data from the array that corresponds with the selected `indexPath.row`, which it does.

Now here's the issue. Once I'm in the `DetailVC`, I want to make a button that lets me switch the displayed data to the previous or next `indexPath.row`. To explain it better, below is some **Pseudo-Code** that explains what I'm trying to do

```
@IBAction func nextIndex(_ sender: Any) {
     self.view.indexPath.row = self.view.indexPath.row +1
        or
     self.datasource = next datasource index
}
```

Now what would I need to do to transition between these indexPaths from inside the `DetailViewController`? Such as a "go to next" or "go to previous" or "go to [selected path]" button?

I feel there may be a simple answer to this that I'm not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: You can implement singleton, manager that will be responsible for this. e.g.

```
class AnimalManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = AnimalManager()

    private var animals = [Animal]()
    private var currentIndex: Int?

    .....
}
```

Now you can implement such methods like: current animal, next animal, revious, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I can't find any documentation on "singlet manager"

Comment: sorry my mistake there should be singleton, not singlet. Singleton is a design pattern